# Timestamp in Photobucket api

Tags: api, photobucket

I want to use Photobucket API and I was going through its documentation and i came across this line which says:-

= 1208290131

then further I came across the line

= oauth_consumer_key=1020304&oauth_nonce=5c4b38eb7e7f0a0603452dfb3bf149d7&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1208290131&oauth_version=1.0

Now my question is what is this timestamp & how is this used...

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

timestamp is a parameter you have to send on api requests so they know when the request was made.
usually programming languages have methods to get you the value right away.

e.g.
PHP time()

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php